# When do foods with a use-by date really go bad?

Tags: food-safety, chicken

UPDATE:
All the [standard recommendations](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/21068/how-long-can-i-store-a-food-in-the-pantry-refrigerator-or-freezer) say you can only store refrigerated raw chicken for 1-2 days, but that seems really conservative, since it's designed for immunocompromised people. Therefore, I'm left wondering, what is the *practical* limit where a reasonable adult with no health issues should actually throw food away (while it still has no obvious signs of spoilage like mold or smell)? Perhaps more like 1 week in the example of chicken?

ORIGINAL QUESTION:
I have a pack of raw chicken breasts that has been in the refrigerator about 1 month (28 days) past its "use by" date. It is the type on a foam tray with a plastic wrapper, still sealed in the original packaging. Upon opening it, it smells fine, and there are no off-colors. Is this still safe?

Comment: Welcome! We get many questions like yours and you need to realize that there’s a difference between „safe“ and „spioiled“. One is a statistical value indicating a low enough probability of spoilage, the other is about the individual item at hand and (bar obvious indicators like color, mold or smell) can only be determined in a lab for the specific sample. We deal only with food _safety_ here (see the previous sentence) and your pack certainly isn’t safe a month past the use by date, which is in itself about food safety (unlike a best before, which is about quality).

Comment: This one https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/12953/100451 answers my question better than the duplicate link.